# randomly set attribute value in the xml from string

Tags: php, xml, dom, for-loop

i have one string in textfile.
i am try to get text from this file and push in to xml attribute value.
this is my code:-

```
<?php
$region = file_get_contents('activity.text');
$arr1 = explode(',',$region);
$arr1[array_rand($arr1)];
$ran1 = $arr1;

// create doctype
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");

// display document in browser as plain text 
// for readability purposes
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
// create root element
$root = $dom->createElement("products");
$dom->appendChild($root);


//for($i=0,$j=351;$i<count($arr1);$i++,$j++)
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{
$pro_id = $dom->createElement("product_id");
$root -> appendChild($pro_id);
//append attribute ib product_id
$attpro = $dom->createAttribute("value");
$pro_id -> appendChild($attpro);
//append attribue value in product_id
$attval = $dom->createTextNode($i+1);
$attpro -> appendChild($attval);

// create child dist_region
$dist_region = $dom->createElement("dist_region");
$pro_id->appendChild($dist_region);
// create attribute node
$attreg = $dom->createAttribute("value");
$dist_region->appendChild($attreg);
// create attribute value node
$attval = $dom->createTextNode("$ran1[$i]");
$attreg->appendChild($attval);

}
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

this is my string(region.txt):-

```
10066,10067,10068,10069,10070,10071,10072,5
```

here i am try to randomly push text from the string in to xml file as a attribute value with this my code output is:-

```
<products>
    <product_id value="1">
        <dist_activity value="10066"/>
        <dist_activity value="10066"/>
    </product_id>
    <product_id value="2">
        <dist_activity value="10067"/>
        <dist_activity value="10067"/>
    </product_id>
</products>
```

i want output something like this type:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
    <product_id value="1">
        <dist_activity value="10066"/>
        <dist_activity value="10069(any thing not same)"/>
    </product_id>
    <product_id value="2">
        <dist_activity value="10067"/>
        <dist_activity value="10072(any thing not same)"/>
    </product_id>
</products>
```

randomly get the attribute value from the string
thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is more with getting the values into the wished order than adding the XML elements. Some hints:

- You can make use of `shuffle()` to randomize the whole array. See http://php.net/shuffle
- You can make use of `array_chunk()` to make a group of two values each. See http://php.net/array_chunk

Code-Example:

```
$values = explode(',', '10066,10067,10068,10069,10070,10071,10072,5');

shuffle($values);

$groups = array_chunk($values, 2);
print_r($groups);

$count = count($groups);

foreach ($groups as $index => $group)
{
    $last = $index+1 === $count;
    printf(" %s─ product_id: %d\n", $last ? '└' : '├', $index + 1);

    foreach ($group as $subindex => $value)
    {
        printf(" %s   %s─ dist_activity: %s\n", $last ? ' ' : '│', $subindex ? '└' : '├', $value);
    }
    if (!$last) print(" │\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10069
            [1] => 10068
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10072
            [1] => 10067
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 10070
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10071
            [1] => 10066
        )

)
 ├─ product_id: 1
 │   ├─ dist_activity: 10069
 │   └─ dist_activity: 10068
 │
 ├─ product_id: 2
 │   ├─ dist_activity: 10072
 │   └─ dist_activity: 10067
 │
 ├─ product_id: 3
 │   ├─ dist_activity: 5
 │   └─ dist_activity: 10070
 │
 └─ product_id: 4
     ├─ dist_activity: 10071
     └─ dist_activity: 10066
```

[See it in action.](http://eval.in/16120)